# Suppose we roll 10 fair six-sided dice. Probability of getting exactly two 2's and three 3's?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

Here's my solution, but as usual with combinatorics problems, I tend to be convinced of my errors too early. So I'd like to know what you guys think. Is this correct?

$\frac{\binom{10}{2} \binom{10}{3} 4^5}{6^{10}}$

Justification: There are $6^{10}$ ways of rolling of 10 dice. Now there are 10 choose 2 ways of having exactly two 2's among the dice, and 10 choose 3 ways of having three 3's. In addition, the remaining 5 dice may have any values except 2 or 3, which is $4^5$ ways of choosing them.

Right, right?

Comment: start with 5 dice and add one dice at a time until n=10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost.

Once you have selected 2 of the 10 places for the twos, there are only 8 places remaining; then select 3 of these for the threes.

$$\dfrac{\dbinom{10}{2}\;\dbinom{8}{3}\;4^5}{6^{10}}$$

Comment: Great, thanks! How does one stop making these mistakes in combinatorics. Is it just practice, practice, practice?

Comment: Pretty much,  @Isa .